# 120vac outdoor wifi camera?

Tags: electrical, wiring

Is there a wifi camera out there that has a built in power supply and can be directly wired to 120vac? I've looked and looked and all I can come up with is one with a separate power supply. I want to wire it in to my motion sensor light.
Thanks in advance,
Greg

Comment: Questions seeking product or service recommendations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly.

Comment: Two new contributors, one looking for a product and one promoting a product.

Comment: This is _not_ and endorsement because I have never used the brand or product, but I have seen these ["flood light bulb" cameras](https://www.amazon.com/Sengled-Floodlight-Security-Motion-Activated-Wireless/dp/B07GK6LGCV).  They screw right in - no wiring or power supply needed.

Answer (score 1):

The Ring Floodlight is designed to replace a traditional floodlight, and has the motion sensor built in. But it's expensive and requires a base station.

Answer (score 0):

### You won't find such a product

Nobody will build it, because it's a heck of a lot easier getting a low-voltage device through the **UL Listing** process than a 120V mains product.

### You wouldn't want it, either (most of the time)

You also would not benefit from the easier rules afforded to low voltage wiring, which is also relevant to cameras which wire via Ethernet etc. Ethernet is allowed to run with low voltage power, but for mains power, ethernet would need to run separately.  In fact, a 120V camera would be a safety disaster, because people would simply disregard Code and install it with the lazy sloppiness that is normally allowed for low voltage wiring.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and advice well taken. I was hoping they would make some sort of camera (wi fi) that would screw into the existing weatherproof box that I mounted the motion sensor light to. It's funny the manufacturer of the light added additional wiring to light up more flood lights (can switch up to 1kw) so I thought of using one of the existing holes in the weatherproof box or adding a new weatherproof box.

Comment: Sure, extend to another weatherproof box, stick a 120V receptacle there with an outdoor in-use cover, and stick the wall-wart in that.  That's the code legal way anyway.

Comment: Thanks, didn't think of that! To try and run Ethernet wires where I want them is almost impossible without making a major project out of it. I really appreciate your input.